# Reorder operation is not working in backpack for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

Reorder operation is not working in backpack for laravel.

Migration file:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('complexities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('parent_id')->default(0)->nullable();
            $table->integer('lft')->default(0)->nullable();
            $table->integer('rgt')->default(0)->nullable();
            $table->integer('depth')->default(0)->nullable();
        });
    }
```

Crud controller

```
use ReorderOperation;
..........
.........
protected function setupReorderOperation()
    {
        $this->crud->set('reorder.label', 'title');
        $this->crud->set('reorder.max_level', 2);
    }
```

I am getting the Reorder UI, But it is not working. I mean can reorder the list, But no effect in database and list becomes in old order when I reload it.

Comment: This will sound like a dumb question, but sometimes people miss this when there are a lot of entries. Have you clicked the SAVE button at the end? Have you seen a green notification bubble confirming the save has happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the `nullable` on all fields. Please try with

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('complexities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('parent_id')->nullable()->default(0);
        $table->integer('lft')->default(0);
        $table->integer('rgt')->default(0);
        $table->integer('depth')->default(0);
    });
}
```

Also check if there are any values stored for these fields in the database.

Comment: nothing saved in database.
also, not working...

Comment: This is working well, the problem was I did not notice the save button. 
So, I never hit this one.